# Wordpress - How to change the category page to full list views?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to change the category page to show all its post in a single category page, without any pagination, meta tags, snippets and images. Like the "Recent Posts" widget.

Is that possible? I tried a code in the theme functions but no luck. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [child theme](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/) of the main theme. And then create a category.php file in the child theme so that it override the parent theme category.php. Then you can use the [WordPress loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) to list the cateogry post as you desire.

Comment: @DilipKumar Glad to help. :)